# Выравнивание блоков в bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Использую Bootstrap для верстки сайта.
Когда задаю различную ширину блоков с контентом,
то они начинают скакать и появляются большие отступы.
Я знаю, что это тривиальный вопрос, но как мне сделать так,
чтобы исчезло пустое пространство между блоками разной высоты?
Какие методы существуют для подобного выравнивания?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Указать для этих элементов stretch

...

Comment: Подозреваю, что автор вопроса хочет masonry layout, а не растянуть элементы. Хотя мало ли.

Comment: Stretch –  это что-то близкое к тому, что мне нужно. Попробую объяснить еще: я ищу способ сделать одинаковую высоту у блоков в одной строке так, чтобы эта высота была равна самому высокому блоку из строки. Почему-то мне кажется, что таких методов должно существовать множество

Comment: Masonry layout это тоже изящное решение, которое мне может подойти, т.к. я рассматриваю любые методы подобного выравнивания блоков. Спасибо!